# Uso dell'espressione "spuntarla"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, idioms, colloquial

Sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/spuntarla) ho trovato il verbo procomplementare "spuntarla", che non conoscevo. Secondo questo vocabolario, si tratta di un'espressione di uso comune con il significato seguente:

> riuscire a ottenere ciò che ci si è prefissati superando ostacoli e difficoltà.

Il dizionario ne fa questo esempio:

> *dopo lunghe discussioni l’ho spuntata*.

Ho anche trovato che ha lo stesso significato che ["averla vinta"](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/averla-vinta).

Tuttavia, non mi è del tutto chiaro come si utilizza. Si tratta di un verbo di uso colloquiale o informale? Potreste indicarmi altri esempi di uso?

Comment: Sì, l’uso di “spuntare/spuntarla” nel senso di riuscire a ottenere qualcosa di difficile è un uso colloquiale molto comune. “*Dopo tanti sforzi son riuscito a spuntarla; è così testardo che la spunta sempre lui. Dopo lunghe trattative sono riuscito a spuntare ottime condizioni.*”

Comment: Alla base c’è sempre una contrattazione (su un prezzo, su condizioni, etc.).